# Postgres insert multiple rows if does not exist, return all id's if exists or inserted, then use all ids to insert into another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an array of strings in a node server. I want to insert each string as a tag into table1. Each tag row has tag_id, and tag_text, where tag_id is a serial value, and tag_text is the corresponding string.

I want to insert these tags if they do not already exist, and return the id's of all the tags, whether each one was inserted or already existed. Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Furthermore, I would like to use the returned id's from the query above and insert each id along with a constant value (defined in the node server) in another table (table2). Is it possible to do all of this in a single transaction? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the returning clause:

```
insert into table1 (tag)
    select tag
    from unnest($tag_array) tag
    on conflict (tag)
    do update set tag = excluded.tag
    returning (*);
```

This should return all tags, whether or not they are in the table.